# SwiftHTTP is installed but can't import it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I created a new Xcode 7 project in swift. I quit then Xcode, and create the pod file.

```
pod init
```

Then I edited the file with the configuration provided:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftHTTP', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Then:

```
$ pod install              

Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using SwiftHTTP (1.0.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

I reopened my Xcode project and added `import SwiftHTTP` but the build failed with this error : `No such module 'SwiftHTTP'`

I rechecked the documentation but that's all I have, I did missed something but I don't know what it is !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I reopened my Xcode project

Please make sure you do not open the Xcode project file but the workspace instead (file with suffix .xcworkspace) that CocoaPods created in your project folder.

Comment: Indeed, thanks but now I have the issue: `Cannot load underlying module for 'SwiftHTTP'`

Comment: According to similar questions here on SO it may help to run the project at least once.

Comment: What do you mean run the project ? How I can do that if I can't build it ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the installation of Xcode 7.1 (I was with 7.0).

Answer (score 0):

well it's kinda late but what iOSX was saying + for the future reference, these cases can be solved when you run the project (xcworkspace)

when new pods are installed and you try to import it, xcode may not know the existence of the new pod modules until you 'run' it, which builds the project again and gets to know the existence of those modules then wallah! it works!